# Delete one record in MS Access database and update the rest by giving them new ascending number

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I have an Access DB file which contains one table and for example ten records in it. Every record has an ascending number but not as a key. It's just used by VB application to order the appearance of records. I know the way to delete every selected record through my application, but I can't find the way to update the rest nine records by giving them a new ascending number. For example, if I delete the 5th record, I want my app to count the remaining records and give them a new ascending number...

I have done something like this, but of course it doesn't do the job...

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class ApplicationForm

    Public Provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Public DataFile As String = "database.accdb"
    Public ConnString As String = Provider & DataFile
    Public MyConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub AppsPaths_DelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AppsPaths_DelButton.Click
        MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
        MyConnection.Open()

        Dim DBCount As Integer = AppsCount_Label2.Text
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim strDelete As String
        Dim strUpdate As String
        strDelete = "DELETE FROM  ApplicationsPaths WHERE TagNum = '" & AppToDel_Label.Text & "'"
        Dim cmdDelete As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strDelete, MyConnection)
        Do
            strUpdate = "UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '" & i.ToString & "'"
            i += 1
        Loop Until i = DBCount
        Dim cmdUpdate As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strUpdate, MyConnection)
        Try
            cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmdDelete.Dispose()
            cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmdUpdate.Dispose()
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why bother? It's only the relative values that matter for the purpose of ordering, not the absolute values. You can just leave the holes there and the resulting sort will be exactly the same.

Comment: No I can't do that because application loads all this records into programmatically added controls and it uses this ascending number. So if I remove any other record except the last one, application loads nothing, or it loads some of them. The same thing happens when I try to add a new record through my application. Even if one record is missing except the last one, everything messing up!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of your procedures require consecutive numbers I would suggest using a query with a running-total-type calculation, instead of the table.  I'm not brushed up on VB.Net but I'd imagine you can refer to a query just as easy as referring to the table.

Here is my table of data with missing ID's:

[image: table]

This SQL query provides unique consecutive ID's called `IncID`:

```
SELECT DCount("id","table2","id<=" & [id]) AS IncID, thing FROM Table2;
```

And here is the result:

[image: query result]

Comment: The DCount / DSum method of displaying running counts/totals is the recommended method from the company that developed both VB.NET and Access, which are the platforms in question.  "Imagine if you had to update 10,000 rows" isn't solid logic. Databases were built to handle calculations.  Also, just to make sure, **I just tested with 100,000 records and the result was instantaneous.**

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you only call your update statement once and the update statement doesn't include a criteria so it will update all your rows. Call the update statement in the loop and include a criteria so it will only update one row at a time. I assume AppsCount_Label2 holds your total rows in that table. Skip calling the statement when the counter is equal to the deleted one.

```
Private Sub AppsPaths_DelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AppsPaths_DelButton.Click
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
    MyConnection.Open()

    Dim DBCount As Integer = AppsCount_Label2.Text
    Dim i As Integer = 0, j As Integer = 0
    Dim strDelete As String
    Dim strUpdate As String
    strDelete = "DELETE FROM  ApplicationsPaths WHERE TagNum = '" & AppToDel_Label.Text & "'"

    Try
        Dim cmdDelete As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strDelete, MyConnection)
        cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmdDelete.Dispose()

        Do
            i += 1
            If i <> AppToDel_Label.Text Then
                j += 1
                strUpdate = "UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '" & j.ToString & "' WHERE TagNum = '" & i.ToString & "'"
                Dim cmdUpdate As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strUpdate, MyConnection)
                cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmdUpdate.Dispose()
            End If
        Loop Until i = DBCount

        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Let's say you have 5 rows and you delete the TagNum = 2. The delete statement is `DELETE FROM ApplicationsPaths WHERE TagNum = '2'`. The update statement in each iteration is like this:

```
UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '1' WHERE TagNum = '1'
UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '2' WHERE TagNum = '3'
UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '3' WHERE TagNum = '4'
UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '4' WHERE TagNum = '5'
```

When variable i = 2 (deleted TagNum), it skips the execution of update statement and increment of variable j. But this code is not good if you have lots of rows in the table because there will be n-1 execution of update statement where n is the number of rows before the delete statement. RDBMS works in a set of rows instead of individual row. So it's better to update all the records in a batch. Let's modify the code.

First update the TagNum type in the table to numeric type.

```
Private Sub AppsPaths_DelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AppsPaths_DelButton.Click
    Try
        MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
        MyConnection.Open()
        Dim strQuery As String

        Dim DBCount As Integer = AppsCount_Label2.Text

        strQuery = "DELETE FROM ApplicationsPaths WHERE TagNum = " & AppToDel_Label.Text
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(strQuery, MyConnection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        strQuery = "UPDATE ApplicationsPaths SET TagNum = TagNum - 1 WHERE TagNum > " & AppToDel_Label.Text
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(strQuery, MyConnection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Let's say that you still have 5 rows and you delete TagNum = 3 now. The delete statement is `DELETE FROM ApplicationsPaths WHERE TagNum = 3`. The update statement is `UPDATE ApplicationsPaths SET TagNum = TagNum - 1 WHERE TagNum > 3`. You only execute the update statement once and it affects only 2 rows (TagNum = 4 and TagNum = 5). Imagine if you have thousands of rows. How many update statements are executed if you use the first code? You can optimize the first code to skip execution of update when the variable i is lower than AppToDel_Label, but it stil execute many times repeatedly.

EDIT: Optimize the first code so it skips unnecessary updates.

```
MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
MyConnection.Open()

Dim DBCount As Integer = AppsCount_Label2.Text
Dim i As Integer = 0, j As Integer = AppToDel_Label.Text
Dim strDelete As String
Dim strUpdate As String
strDelete = "DELETE FROM ApplicationsPaths WHERE TagNum = '" & AppToDel_Label.Text & "'"

Try
    Dim cmdDelete As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strDelete, MyConnection)
    cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmdDelete.Dispose()

    Do
        i += 1
        If i > AppToDel_Label.Text Then
            strUpdate = "UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '" & j.ToString & "' WHERE TagNum = '" & i.ToString & "'"
            Dim cmdUpdate As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strUpdate, MyConnection)
            cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmdUpdate.Dispose()
            j += 1
        End If
    Loop Until i = DBCount

    MyConnection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

If you have 5 rows and delete TagNum = 3. The update statements are:

```
UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '3' WHERE TagNum = '4'
UPDATE [ApplicationsPaths] SET [TagNum] = '4' WHERE TagNum = '5'
```

TagNum = 1 and TagNum = 2 update statements are not needed because TagNum values aren't changed. But it's still not good if you have lots of because it update the rows individually.

Comment: The **DCount** method is fine.  See comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47606998/8112776).

Comment: @ashleedawg I have deleted my comment about DCount.